# open every Window form as child to MdiParent

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having `MdiParent` form which has `Menu` and `Submenu`
Parent Form is Say **Form A** if I open **Form B** using submenu option using following code

```
B addbill = new B();
B.Show();
B.MdiParent = this;
```

It opens **Form B** as child of **Form A**. Now I want to open **Form C** from **Form B** after click the Button on **Form B** and **Form B** will be closed and **Form C** will be opened as Child of **Form A**
Again after click button on **Form C** , **Form C** Will be closed and **Form B** will be opened as **Form A**

So what can I do to do same ?

Answer (score 7):

On FormB button click event write this code:

```
 FormC fc=new FormC();
 fc.MdiParent=this.MdiParent;
 fc.Show();
```

And in FormC load event write this code:

```
FormB fb=new FormB();
fb.Hide();
fb.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to use dependency injection to resolve your forms via eg: autofac or similar then I found this pattern to be ideal, simply createa function like so in your MdiContainer form:

```
private void CreateAndShowChildForm<TFormType>() where TFormType : Form
{
    //check if form is already open
    var form = MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TFormType));
    if (form == null)
    {
        //create the new form
        form = ServiceLocator.Container.Resolve<TFormType>();
    }

    //parent and show the form
    form.MdiParent = this;
    form.Show();
}
```

Then for the click/interaction/menu events I can simply call:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CreateAndShowChildForm<frmMyFormName>();
}
```

I hope this is somewhat useful for anyone else out there looking for a somewhat clean way of doing this sort of thing.

In the main program.cs file I would have done something like this:

```
internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ...

        // Create the container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register any other types you want resolved via DI
        ...

        // Register your Forms
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)));

        // Create your static service locator singleton
        ServiceLocator.Container = builder.Build();

        // Resolve Entry Point and Run.
        var reg = ServiceLocator.Container.IsRegistered<frmMain>();
        if (reg)
        {
            var entryPoint = ServiceLocator.Container.Resolve<frmMain>();
            Application.Run(entryPoint);
        }
    }
}

// You can shove this in it's own file somewhere in your project...
public static class ServiceLocator
{
    public static IContainer Container { get; set; }
}
```

I've simplified it - might want to add in some error dialogs or exception handling as needed and so on, but this illustrates the idea.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

before B is closed:

```
C.MdiParent = B.MdiParent; // which is pointing to A
```

Comment: so do i need to create object of B ? B objB = new B(); C objC= new C(); objC.MdiParent=objB.MdiParent; objB.Close();

Answer (score 0):

In Form B button click where you are calling Form C, you have to assign the MdiParent of FormB to MdiParent of FormC which is FormA. After that you can close FormB.

//FormB Button Click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormC frm = new FormC();
            frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; // assign MdiParent of FormB to FormC
            frm.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: it gives an error Form cannot be both an MDI child and MDI parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Analysis an = new Analysis();//on login click open anothe form on same perrent
        an.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        an.Show();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Work..Try This Code

```
 private void btCountSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool exist = false;
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f.Text == "Counter Sale")
            {
                exist = true;
                f.BringToFront();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (exist == false)
        {
            frmCounterSale fm = new frmCounterSale();
            fm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; 
            fm.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Work..Try This Code

```
 private void btCountSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool exist = false;
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f.Name== "frmCounterSale")
            {
                exist = true;
                f.BringToFront();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (exist == false)
        {
            frmCounterSale fm = new frmCounterSale();
            fm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; 
            fm.Show();
        }
    }
```